# How to decompose $SO(3)$ tensors into irreducible parts?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

From A. Zee's book *Group Theory in a Nutshell*, the author claimed to decompose a $SO(3)$ tensor space full of tensors of form $P^{ijk}$ into irreducible subspaces made of tensors of form $\tilde U, W, X$.

The problem is that I can't see how to uniquely decompose $P^{ijk}$ into a linear sum of $\tilde U, W, X$. I need this sum to be explicit to understand.

> Suppose we are given two $SO(3)$ tensors: a symmetric traceless tensor $S^{i j}$ and a vector $T^{k} .$ They furnish the 5-dimensional and the 3-dimensional irreducible representations, respectively. The product $P^{i j k}=S^{i j} T^{k}$ is manifestly a 3-indexed tensor containing $5 \cdot 3=$ 15 components, but $P^{i j k}$ is certainly not a totally symmetric traceless 3 -indexed tensor. It is symmetric and traceless in the first two indices, but has no particular symmetry on the interchange of $j$ and $k$, for example. In chapter IV.1, we learned that the irreducible representations of $S O(3)$ are furnished by symmetric traceless tensors. So, the game is to beat $P^{i j k}$ into a linear combination of symmetric traceless tensors.

It continues

[image]

Comment: What is that you did not understand? What Zee did is to reduce every piece of the $P^{ijk}$ tensor, with the sole properties that a $SO(3)$ tensors has to have.

Comment: @DavideMorgante I don't understand how to write $P^{ijk}$ into a linear sum of $\tilde U, W, X$, and why such a linear sum is unique.

Comment: @MaudPieTheRocktorate in the part you included as a graphics file, he explicitly constructs $\tilde U$, $W$ and $X$ (via $U$ and $V$).